# Toggle button is crashing app when using setOnCheckedChangeListener - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, togglebutton

Just started learning programming and copied an example from [google developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton) but when I try to open the app it just crashes

```
dedo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
            }
        }
    });
```

[Full code](https://hastebin.com/viliyureme.java)

[XML](https://hastebin.com/ihukaqumir.xml)

[Log](https://hastebin.com/iniyixiveg.cs)

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Comment: Post the error so that the problem could be better understood

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Is that useful?

Comment: @afhamu Is that useful?

Comment: yes it is but you need to also update your question and add the rest of the code

Comment: post your whole code for the activity you are using, in the stacktrace it's saying that there is a null reference for a switch

Comment: @TomyGaspar `toggle` is `null`.

Comment: @beastlyCoder There´s the full code, also the reference to a switch is corrected, I was trying to see if  I could used a switch instead

Comment: Could you show your XML file

Comment: @AbderazakAmiar There's the XML file where the toggle is located

Comment: What about SectionsPagerAdapter class could you show it ?

Comment: @AbderazakAmiar https://hastebin.com/kogixapaza.java

Comment: The issue isn't come in your Toggle Button

Comment: Try this in new project : https://hastebin.com/avusufiyot.http  and https://hastebin.com/ititomarop.xml

Comment: I can't know where come in the issue if i don't have the full project

Answer (score 0):

replace your with with this,

```
dedo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    //do something
                }else {
                    //do something else
                }
            }
        });
```